# I need to change my QUERY to avoid unwanted entry

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I've made this query to retrieve data that contains the date displayed at G1 from an imported range, and everything has been working fine so far.

Today, after inputting `26/09/2019` at G1, for some reason, the query returned more than expected: not only returned all entries from today but also returned `06/08/2019 10:29:47`. (Obs: At Col1, the dates are stored like "`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`")

Then, after doing some testing, I realized that a change as little as adding one second to the undesired entry (ie: `06/08/2019 10:29:48`) would make it disappear from the query.

Now, I'm wondering what kind of change to my formula would avoid such problem from happening again.

My formula:

```
=QUERY(ExternalSheet;"select Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9 where Col1 contains '"&$G$1&"'";0)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet for debugging?

Comment: Welcome. Please add some sample input data including an indication of the data type (it should be clear if something that looks as a date is really being parsed as a date by Google Sheets or if it's parsed as a text value)